# certificate selected by provision profile is incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have created certificate & provisioning profile related to my iphone app.

but when I run app it shows **doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain**

& then I realize that it is not certificate which i have created.

what should I do now?

I have tried to delete previous certificate but it does also not working it again came back.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the private key used to create the certificate present in your keychain app for you to be able to code sign your app. Start fresh, create  a new certificate, this time make sure to store the private key as .p12 file.

Comment: Provisining profile should point to new certificate but it actually not. i dont know why?

Comment: Check the provision profile's bundle identifier is same as your app's bundle identifier. I think thats the culprit. It will be inside app's info.plist

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed the .p12 file. Please go through the Apple docs for Certificate/Provisioning-profile creation process. That will help you to understand the whole process of signing an iOS app.

Comment: Provisining profile should point to new certificate but it actually not. i dont know why?

Comment: Open KeyChain Access and check whether your Certificate is valid or not? And again, I want to ask whether you have installed .p12 file by double clicking on it?

Comment: yes i have done it but now it gives me error **Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' can't be found**
what is should be for?

Comment: In the Code Signing of Build Settings of your Target, you must choose the correct provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can always verify certificate, which provision created with. 
Provision profile have public key encoded in base64. You can compare hash sums or finger print with private key on your mac.

Here is example code how to export certificate from provision in ruby [gist.gitgub](https://gist.github.com/punksta/0468b0174659d86065ebff766cb89796)